# Android: Hide AlertDialog title

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to set the AlertDialog title, but not render it?

I want TalkBack to be able to announce the AletDialog(I found that setting the title of the dialog is the only way to achieve that, let me know if not) when presented, but not display the title for the user.